# onclick select child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that can have many child elements. This super div has a class of `.clickable`, and the child divs also have a `.clickable` class. I also have a `.click` event handler for anything with class `.clickable`.

However, every time I click inside the super div, only the super div gets a click event triggered. The child divs are never being targeted. How do I get around this?

```
html
<div class="super clickable">
 <div id="child-1" class="child clickable"></div>
 <div id="child-2" class="child clickable"></div>
</div>

js
$('.clickable').click(function() {
 $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
});
```

Comment: Just a guess until I can test it but what about $(this).find('.child').css('border','1px solid red');

Comment: I think if you need different behaviour you will need to bind to a different class or selector. Using clickable on the parent and the child is confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [child selector `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) in order to select direct `.clickable` elements within `.clickable` elements:

```
$('.clickable > .clickable').click(function() {
 $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
});
```

Comment: was that answered within a a minute!!! how did you read the question this fast !!!!!!!!!

Comment: @NaeemShaikh Lots of practice :)

Comment: that was lightening speed

Comment: hmm.. its not working for me. Its even turning off the parent's click event. what do you think?

Comment: yea... it does work on jsfiddle, idk why its being retarded for me locally

Comment: @JoshCrozier wait, these child divs are being added using jQuery .append, I'm appending them to the parent div. Is that why its not working for me?

Comment: I think you need this: $('.clickable, .clickable > .clickable').click(function() {

http://jsfiddle.net/abhiklpm/w6uf5p7h/2/

Answer (score 1):

even if there is a nice answer by [josh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28410281/3556874), I would say dont use same classes to trigger different events.

> **IMO** CSS classes can be nested , if the purpose is to style elements.
> if there are events to be bound based on classes, better not nest
> them, try different classes for parent and children

**why**:

You used `.clickable` for both parent and child, So I guess you will further require to attach another event for the parent as well.

See this:

```
$('.clickable > .clickable').click(function() {
 $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
});
```

This will work like a charm, but consider a possibility that you require to add another event to the parent div itself and you do something like

```
$('.clickable ').click(function() {
// make some operation on parent
});
```

This will also trigger click event on the children(because of-course they have same class) while you need parent to be clicked.

So you can do something like this, which would be a better practice

```
<div class="super">  // removed the clickable class from parent
 <div id="child-1" class="child clickable"></div>
 <div id="child-2" class="child clickable"></div>
</div>

js
$('.clickable').click(function() {
 $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
});
```

Thats it.. and then you will not mess up your code in future

**Edit:**

Now as you have used double classes and as [LinkinTED](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1930721/linkinted)  states in comment below: you can do something like `$(.child.clickable)` and `$('.super.clickable')` to differentiate the events for parent and children, but truely speaking this makes your class `clickable` worth of no use. **So the key is simply avoid nesting the same classes if you want to attach events on them.**

Comment: I agree to you on the double named classes, different classes is clearer and less chance of failure. But since the TS is using two classes on one element, you could also use `$('.super.clickable')` for the parent and `$(.child.clickable)` for the children (please note that there *isn't* a whitespace between the both classes, meaning that the element must have both classes.

Comment: then that doesnt make sense for using the `clickable` class at all

Answer (score 0):

For those cases where you don't know (or don't care) who the children are, you can try:

```
$(".super div").click(function () {
    // do stuff
});
```

Or, using jQuery's `.children()` method:

```
$(".super").children().click(function () {
    // do stuff
});
```

And if you need to target a specific child element:

```
// targets second child element
$(".super div").eq(2).click(function () {
    // do stuff
});

could also do $(".super div:first") or $(".super div:last")  
or even $(".super div:last-child") depending on your needs
```

Then  you don't need to know what the children are named.  You essentially access them directly.

Comment: I got a -2 on my suggested answer?  (http://gyazo.com/a7fce527e867ad07bfe541523e6bacba)  Any enlightenment as to why?